# postgresql daysdiff between two dates grouped by month

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the date columns (start_date, end_date) and I want to calculate the difference between these dates and grouped by the month.

I am able to get the datediff in days, but I do not know how to group this in month, any suggestions?

```
Table:
id       Start_date   End_date      days      
1234     2014-06-03   2014-07-05     32
12345    2014-02-02   2014-05-10     97

Expected results:
month  diff_days
2      26
3      30
4      31
5      10
6      27    
7      5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your expected output numbers are off a little. You might want to double-check.

I use a calendar table myself, but this query uses a CTE and date arithmetic. Avoiding the hard-coded date '2014-01-01' and the interval for 365 days is straightforward, but it makes the query harder to read, so I just used those values directly.

```
with your_data as (
  select date '2014-06-03' as start_date, date '2014-07-05' as end_date union all
  select '2014-02-02', '2014-05-10'
), calendar as (
  select date '2014-01-01' + (n || ' days')::interval calendar_date
  from generate_series(0, 365) n
)
select extract (month from calendar_date) calendar_month, count(*) from calendar
inner join your_data on calendar.calendar_date between start_date and end_date
group by calendar_month
order by calendar_month;
```

```
calendar_month  count
--
2               27
3               31
4               30
5               10
6               28
7               5
```

As a rule of thumb, you should never group by the month alone--doing that risks grouping data from different years. This is a safer version that includes the year, and which also restricts output to a single calendar year.

```
with your_data as (
  select date '2014-06-03' as start_date, date '2014-07-05' as end_date union all
  select '2014-02-02', '2014-05-10' 
), calendar as (
  select date '2014-01-01' + (n || ' days')::interval calendar_date
  from generate_series(0, 700) n
)
select extract (year from calendar_date) calendar_year, extract (month from calendar_date) calendar_month, count(*) from calendar
inner join your_data on calendar.calendar_date between start_date and end_date
where calendar_date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
group by calendar_year, calendar_month
order by calendar_year, calendar_month;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked. Good point on the grouping of different years, I am currently using a case statement to show data only for the current year (case when date '2014-01-01' + (n || ' days')::interval < '2014-12-31' THEN date '2014-01-01' + (n || ' days')::interval END) calendar_date. This pretty much is limited to this year, I do have end_dates which run into the 2015 any idea how to extract and group those without impeding on the 2014 months?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ecd8f/3)

```
with min_max as (
    select min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date
    from t
), g as (
    select daterange(d::date, (d + interval '1 month')::date, '[)') as r
    from generate_series(
        (select date_trunc('month', start_date) from min_max),
        (select end_date from min_max),
        '1 month'
    ) g(d)
)
select *
from (
    select
        to_char(lower(r), 'YYYY Mon') as "Month",
        sum(upper(r) - lower(r)) as days
    from (
        select t.r * g.r as r
        from
            (
                select daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') as r
                from t
            ) t
            inner join
            g on t.r && g.r
    ) s
    group by 1
) s
order by to_timestamp("Month", 'YYYY Mon')
;
  Month   | days 
----------+------
 2014 Feb |   27
 2014 Mar |   31
 2014 Apr |   30
 2014 May |   10
 2014 Jun |   28
 2014 Jul |    5
```

[Range data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html)

[Range functions and operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html)